# Next js - disable server side rendering on some pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to disable ssr on some pages using Next js? For example, I have a page with a product description on which I use ssr for SEO but I also have a page with a list of items or products which I can filter and for that page, I don't want to use ssr because this page generates dynamically every time, how can I disable ssr on this page?

Comment: if you use material ui, there is a `NoSsr` component you can use directly out of the box

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Lazy load the component and disable SSR: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/List'), {
  ssr: false
})

export default () => <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
```

Comment: If there are children inside that no ssr element, what happens? I need the no ssr for my toplevel element that holds other children, would that affect my SEO and performance?

Comment: How to do it at page level?

Comment: This also will not work if the component has named exported variables

Comment: Isn't `export default () => <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />` the same as `export default DynamicComponentWithNoSSR`? Anyway, you saved my day, good precise answer!

Answer (score 152):

The `dynamic()` function can also be used without a dynamic import:

```
// components/NoSsr.jsx

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import React from 'react'

const NoSsr = props => (
  <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>
)

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSsr), {
  ssr: false
})
```

Anything wrapped in this component will not be visible in the SSR source. For example:

```
// inside the page you want to disable SSR for

import NoSsr from "components/NoSsr";

Contact me at <NoSsr>email@example.com</NoSsr>
```

Comment: Works great, can be used to wrap <Component /> in _app.js for debugging

Comment: Excellent because you can use it with `_app` as well.

Comment: One limitation though: it probably have other side effects regarding the way code is loaded. A pure React solution might be sufficient (as described in anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512843/5513532 for instance)

Answer (score 54):

This will disable next.js SSR, put this on your _app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React from "react";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(App), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Comment: That disables SSR for the whole project and the advantages of SSR like SEO-Friendly pages are lost. (Just to take in mind)

Comment: It worked like magic

Comment: It's not necessary to do this for the entire project. You can also use this for specific pages

Comment: SPA speed with next routing; cool hack.

Answer (score 13):

This is a late answer, but in case anyone runs into this:

```
const isServer = () => typeof window === `undefined`;

const Page = () => isServer() ? null : (

  <> 
      <YourClientSideComponent />
  </>
);
```

This is on the "page" level. `isServer()` prevents rendering of anything while on the server side. You could, if you wanted to, prevent ssr on the component level also:

```
const isServer = () => typeof window === `undefined`;

const Page = () =>(

  <> 
      { !isServer() && <YourClientSideComponent /> }
  </>
);
```

Comment: Is the "." before `!isServer` intentional? That is invalid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I had it working in the Next.js project with styled-components in it, but doesn't work always as required. Not sure why!! The accepted solution is best fit

Comment: This will create a mismatch between server-render and client-render, this doesn't actually disable the render.

Answer (score 5):

Based entirly on the answer by Erik Hofer, you can create an HOC to wrap your pages or other components in.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import React from 'react';

const withNoSSR = (Component: React.FunctionComponent) => dynamic(
    () => Promise.resolve(Component),
    { ssr: false },
);

export default withNoSSR;
```

Then use as:

```
import React from 'react';
import withNoSSR from './withNoSSR';

function SomePage() {
    return (
        <div>Only renders in the browser</div>
    );
}

// wrap with HOC on export
export default withNoSSR(SomePage);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use [react-no-ssr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-no-ssr) React component.

Let's say Comments is our client only component. Now we need to render it only on the client. Here's how we do it.

```
import React from 'react';
import NoSSR from 'react-no-ssr';
import Comments from './comments.jsx';

const MyPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>My Blog Post</h2>
    <hr />
    <NoSSR>
      <Comments />
    </NoSSR>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that i just came up with based on the something mentioned in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate

```
class ClientOnly extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isClient: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isClient: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isClient } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;

    return isClient ? children : false;
  }
}
```

You can then wrap any component / block with this and it won't get rendered on the server. e.g.

```
<ClientOnly>You're logged in as {name}</ClientOnly>
```

This also prevents the following React.hydrate warning "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in ."

Comment: Equivalent with hooks would look like this I think: `const useClientCheck =() => { const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false); useEffect(() => { setIsClient(true)}, []); return isClient }`

Answer (score 2):

In @refactor answer, the `react-no-ssr` is not working for some typescript issue.

I just wrote a very simple NoSSR component as below:

```js
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react'

const DefaultOnSSR: React.FC = () => null

export const NoSSR: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode; onSSR?: ReactNode }> = ({ children, onSSR = <DefaultOnSSR /> }) => {
  const [onBrowser, setOnBrowser] = useState(false)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setOnBrowser(true)
  }, [])
  return <>{onBrowser ? children : onSSR}</>
}
```

and can be used anywhere if you want to avoid SSR like below:

```js
const MyPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>My Blog Post</h2>
    <hr />
    <NoSSR>
      <Comments />
    </NoSSR>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This solution gave me "Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format." warning

Answer (score 1):

Another and I believe the simplest solution is to just use `process.browser`, which will only be true when ran on client side.

```
<div>
  {
    process.browser && <Hidden />
  }
</div>
```

Comment: process object in only available in Node

Answer (score 0):

**Late answer**

It's cause an hydration error as well, as I'm using Chakra UI and getting this:

Error: there was an error while hydrating. I fix that by going to Sidebar Component and add these two lines only:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(observer(Sidebar)), {ssr: false})
//in case of you are not using mobx then: 
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Sidebar), {ssr: false})
```

Answer (score 0):

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => <Component {...pageProps} />;

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(App), { ssr: false });