# Is it possible to disable SSR/SSG completely in Next.js?

Tags: build, next.js, config, server-side-rendering

Looking at [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) it seems like you can use `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` as optimizations at build-time (for either static Next.js sites or SSR Next.js sites), and you're *required* to use `getServerSideProps` for SSR.

I'm looking to support both completely static sites (i.e. no SSG/data needed @ build time/serve from nginx or S3) *and* SSR.

**Is there any way to disable SSR completely for the static build (i.e. a build flag)? Or do I need to omit or remove these functions at build-time?**

Comment: Ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip-blocks and https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config to conditionally remove the code at build time.

Comment: just load app component dynamic like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509306/5322183