# Next.JS has "is a client-only hook" error

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm writing my first Next.JS app and am getting this error when I build or deploy:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/"
Error: useLocalStorage is a client-only hook
    at m (/private/var/www/trivia/.next/server/app/page.js:8:2618)
```

My code is as follows:

```
// src/app/page.js
import App from "./App";

export default async function Home() {
  return <App />;
}
```

```
// src/app/App.jsx
"use client";

import { useLocalStorage } from "@uidotdev/usehooks";

export default function App({ quotes, todaysDate }) {
  const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("name", null);

  ...
}
```

In `App.jsx` I have `use client`... doesn't that make it client-side rendered, so I can use hooks here?

I don't really care if it is server-side or client-side rendered for now, I just want to see it run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139884/next-js-disable-server-side-rendering-on-some-pages) you need to encapsulate your app in a component and import it dynamically and disable str rendering

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('<PATH_TO_YOUR_COMPONENT>'), {
  ssr: false
})

export default () => <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
```